# Browse an array of months with 'ngFor' directive

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, binding, ngfor

My lack of knowledge in Angular 2 and typescript led me to this issue :

I want a datatable (already imported well) with all the months of the year on abscissa, and some DB objects on the ordinate (this is OK).

I don't know how and where to declare my list of months and how to browse it in my html.
A this moment, I have this :

Component.ts :

```
  public months= {
    1:'Janvier',
    2:'Février',
    3:'Avril',
    etc...
    12:'Decembre'
  };
```

Component.html

```
<td *ngFor="let month of months">{{month}}</td>
```

Could you help me making it work (displaying at least a raw of months) and as clean as possible ? I'm pretty sure declaring a list of months directly in the class is not a good thing...

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use this way

```
months= [
      { 'id' :1 , 'name':'Janvier'},
      { 'id' :2 , 'name':'Février'},
      { 'id' :3 , 'name':'Avril'}
    ];
```

Accessing it in the **ngFor**  as below

```
<div *ngFor="let month in months">
      {{month.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used this one because I needed to bind the id with my datas. Thank you !

Comment: so is it helpful to you?

Answer (score 4):

You have to make an array of months. Currently you have an object.

```
public months = ["Janvier", "Février", "Avril"...];
```

Or if you really want to have an object, you can implement custom pipe:

```
import { Injectable, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
   name: 'keyObject'
})
@Injectable()
export class KeyObjectPipe {

transform(value, args:string[]):any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
        keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
}
}
```

And then you can use it as:

```
<td *ngFor="let month of months | keyObject">{{month.value}}</td>
```

Comment: Great ideau but piping it each time I ask for a line doesn't please me. At least you ligntened me about it, thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use indexing in your view?

In your TS:

```
months = ["Janvier", "Février", "Avril"...];
```

In your HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let month of months; let i = index">
        <p>Month(string): {{month}}</p>
        <p>Month(number): {{i+1}}</p>
</div>
```